# How do I filter model objects by most recently created in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I am working on a website in Django and I have a model 'Question'. The Question model has a field 'date_created' which is a DateTimeField.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model:
    ...
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

In my view, I want to be able to get all the questions that have been asked in the last 10 days.
Something like this:

```
Question.objects.filter(???)

>> <All the questions that have been asked in the last 10 days>
```

What do I replace '???' with?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to do this

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

ten_days_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=10)
questions_last_10_days = Question.objects.filter(date_created__gte=ten_days_ago)
```

You use `timedelta` to get the datetime of 10 days ago.

Then you use the filter `date_created__gte`.  This is a Django construct that means "date_created that is greater-than or equal to"

Comment: Thanks so much! P.S - Don't start your variables with a number. Again, Thanks - you're a legend!

Answer (score 4):

You might just want to get the most recent N Questions instead.

```py
Question.objects.order_by('-date_created')[:10]
```

Comment: Thanks - but it's not exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyways.